# Webservice request fails for sequential call in Webshpere 7.0

Tags: java, web-services, websphere

I am running into this error when trying to call web service from server side of a Spring based web application.

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed (1), 
reason: RC: 55 The specified network resource or device is no longer available.
```

The web application I am developing is running on WebSphere 7.0 / Windows Server 2008 R2 64bit.

The web service interface is implemented as `javax.iws.WebSerivce` (uses `@WebService` annotation). In my case it has 2 methods implemented with `@WebMethod` annotation which call 2 different methods on web service.

Error happens when I try to call 1st and 2nd methods sequentially one after another. The calling to both of these methods is done in the same server side function:

```
public MyResponse getResponse (...) {

    Res res1 = webServiceInstance.getFstCall()

    Res res2 = webServiceInstance.getSndCall()

}
```

1st method call always succeeds, but I always get the above mentioned error for the 2nd call.

Comment: What is `webServiceInstance`?

Comment: did you ever get a fix for this?

Comment: Nope. We ended up just retrying the call in case of failure. Another idea is to make these calls on different threads.. but did not try this. I think it is WebSphere issue. Applying latest patches to WebSphere might help, but we cannot do it in our environment, so not confirmed.